# Spring factorybean error in Spring 3.1.1 but not in 3.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-3

I have a context file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="aFactoryBean" class="com.kilo.SpecialFactoryBean"
    factory-method="createInstance">
</bean>

</beans>
```

Loading the context of this is failing with an exception `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsNotAFactoryException: Bean named 'aFactoryBean' must be of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean], but was actually of type [com.kilo.SpecialObject]` when using Spring v 3.1.1.RELEASE whereas the same works fine with v 3.1.0.RELEASE. Thought that I might ask here if I am missing something obvious in configuring this, before falsely declaring this as a bug :)

**SpecialFactoryBean.java**

```
package com.kilo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

public class SpecialFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<SpecialObject> {

private static SpecialObject ourInstance;

@Override
public SpecialObject getObject() throws Exception {
    return ourInstance;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return SpecialObject.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
}

public static SpecialObject createInstance() {
    if (ourInstance == null) {
        init();
    }
    return ourInstance;
}

private static void init() {
    ourInstance = new SpecialObject();
}

}
```

**SpecialObject.java**

```
package com.kilo;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SpecialObject {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SpecialObject.class);

public void doSomething() {
    LOG.info("Did something special");
}

}
```

**SpringFBDriver.java**

```
package com.kilo;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringFBDriver {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SpringFBDriver.class);

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:com/kilo/applicationContext.xml");
    LOG.info("Inited");
    doSomething();
}

private static void doSomething() {
    SpecialObject specialObject = applicationContext
            .getBean(SpecialObject.class);
    specialObject.doSomething();
}

}


Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsNotAFactoryException: Bean named 'aFactoryBean' must be of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean], but was actually of type [com.kilo.SpecialObject]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.kilo.SpringFBDriver.main(SpringFBDriver.java:15)
```

Comment: why are you using http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd instead of the one which is 3.1?

Comment: Using 3.1 xsd also didn't change the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are confusing *factory beans* and **Factory Beans** as specified [in the documentation.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

> In Spring documentation, factory bean refers to a bean that is
>   configured in the Spring container that will create objects through an
>   instance or static factory method. By contrast, FactoryBean (notice
>   the capitalization) refers to a Spring-specific FactoryBean .

Your class is already a **FactoryBean** so you don't need to specify it's method factory-method="createInstance" it reserved for factory beans - plain old beans that can create simple objects, not the `FactoryBeans` that are integrated to the bean definitions.

Comment: Awesome @Boris! That explains it I guess - thanks a lot. I think this duality used to work till 3.1.0 but got fixed later on. Will use it in the test setup and confirm.

Comment: Created https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9981 to have beans that try to use both paradigms be notified in a more explicit way.